# Google Contacts API version 3.0 (JAVA) - OAuth2.0 CRUD Operations

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-contacts-api, google-oauth

I am trying to make use of Google Contacts v3 API with OAuth2 authentication. But some of the old sample codes are now not working for this API.

I want to know, if classes in API have detailed,latest and easy documentation available (excluding of those Google has provided)?
Please provide a working code in java if possible. It would be great help.

Comment: Is it just the authentication you're having trouble with? Or specific methods? - if so, which ones?  And what kind of errors are you getting when you say it's "not working"?

Comment: @Amber API provided by google to interact with its servers both for authentication and services are not easy to work with. That's the problem.Did a workaround and managed to work RESTfully(Simple making calls to servers).

Comment: What code or bodies or code were not working? Could you provide stack traces for said code or HTTP responses? Can you post your workaround as an answer or mark this question as closed?